# How to format the json response from ecto join query?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I want to format the join query result from ecto query in specific json. This is the snippet of my ecto query:

```
    query = from(ms in Group,
     join: m in Users,
     on: ms.id == m.group_id,
     select: %{group_id: ms.id, group_name: ms.name, updated_at: 
               ms.updated_at, user_name: m.name, 
               description: m.description},
     where: ms.id == ^group_id
   )
  result =
    query
    |> order_by(desc: :created_at)
    |> Repo.all()
    |> Enum.map(
      &Map.take(&1, [
        :group_id,
        :group_name,
        :updated_at,
        :user_name,
        :description
      ])
    )
```

And the current output response is:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "updated_at": "2019-12-21T12:04:11Z",
      "user_name": "Adam",
      "group_name": "Premium",
      "description": "Romantic Man",
      "group_id": "P001"
    },
    {
      "updated_at": "2019-12-21T12:04:11Z",
      "user_name": "Antony",
      "group_name": "Premium",
      "description": "Strong Man",
      "group_id": "P001"
    }
  ]
}
```

The current response contains redundant data from `Group` database The expected output is:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "group_id": "P001",
    "group_name": "Premium",
    "updated_at": "2019-12-21T12:04:11Z",
    "users": [
      {
        "user_name": "Adam",
        "description": "Romantic Man"
      },
      {
        "user_name": "Antony",
        "description": "Strong Man"
      }
   }
}
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: This is not a formatting issue. You should probably modify the _query_ to use [`Ecto.Query.group_by/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html?#group_by/3). Modifying what was returned in response to this query would be semantically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

try group_by in the query and you'll probably need an array aggregator to get the users the way you want them.  I think you'll need to use a fragment to get the array piece to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
|> Enum.map(
  &Map.take(&1, [
  .....
```

with below snippet

```
|> Enum.group_by(query, & &1.group_id) 
|> Enum.map(fn {_group_id, users} ->

  user_details = Enum.map(users, &Map.take(&1, ~w(user_name description)a))

  hd(users) 
  |> Map.drop(~w(user_name description)a) 
  |> Map.put(:users, user_details)
end)
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.